# bokeh server and flask: get access to a bokeh attribute after submit

Tags: python, flask, bokeh

I'm currently starting to develop a web-app based on flask, where I embedd graphics generated on a separate bokeh server running bokeh applications on the same machine as the flask app. (the bokeh server is a different process from the flask server)

Within flask I access/load a bokeh session by

```
session = pull_session(session_id=None, url='http://mybokehserver:5000/mybokeh')
script = server_session(session_id=session.id, url='http://mybokehserver:5000/mybokeh')
```

The typical

```
return render_template('flask.html', title='Slider example in flask', form=form, script=script )
```

renders the page in flask, then.

This successfully displays e.g. the slider example from the bokeh team within my flask page. The sliders are working, hence, callbacks are operating as expected. Hence, the flask server is a "bokeh client" to my understanding of bokeh terminology.

Now the question is, how can I access attributes from the bokeh widgets, like the value of a slider for the use in the flask server app after submit of the form.

I am searching the web for days now, including the bokeh documentation, but I couldn't find an example or at least I didn't recognize it when I came across.
Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: This would probably require bokeh to either update a database with the new value, or allow the webpage to poll bokeh for the new value.

Comment: My hope was that an object/function like bokeh.io.curdoc in the bokeh-client could do the trick, but I couldn't find an example where anything is read from curdoc().

Comment: If your comfortable using some javascript/jquery, you can send the widget values via ajax - which can be trigged by form submission, or seperate event (such as clicking a button).

Comment: I guess that's true but the motivation to use flask and bokeh, was that I'm familiar with python and clueless (so far) with JS. Hence, I still hope for a pythonic solution.

Comment: Ok so bokeh renders the page, the slider simply just adjusts the prebuilt data filter.  You would have to ADD javascript to that page to capture the value of the slider and onchange notify your API (either through ajax calls or better yet websockets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days more I found the pythonic (or bokehonic) way of doing what I need:
The solution is in "giving names to objects" on the bokeh server side. And claiming access to these object by_name on the client side.

The simplified server side example looks like:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

import numpy as np

x = np.zeros(2)
y = np.zeros(2)
v_src = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y)) 

fig_v = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=300)

fig_v.y_range.name = "y_range_v" # *** giving a name

fig_v.line('x','y',source=v_src, line_width=2,name="voltage") # *** giving a name

plot = gridplot([[fig_v],], toolbar_location='above')
curdoc().add_root(plot)
```

Now I can for example access the fig_v.line object with its attributes and/or the fig_v.yrange object via the pulled session on the (flask) client side and modify it, like:

```
with pull_session(session_id=None, url='http://192.168.3.1:5000/bk_serv') as session:
        script = server_session(session_id=session.id,url='http://192.168.3.1:5000/bk_serv')

        doc = session.document
        line = doc.get_model_by_name("voltage") # *** access via name
        line.data_source.data = dict(x=np.arange(len(some_x_data)), y=some_y_data)

        yrange = doc.get_model_by_name("y_range_v") # *** access via name
        yrange.start=min_somedata
        yrange.end = max_somedata

        return render_template('flask.html', form=form, script=script)
```

I am not sure about the details but the web-socket connection created by bokeh takes care of the update of the plot.

Note: the above code is an excert of the code I wrote. It may not run as is, but I cannot publish the whole work and this excert gives the important information.